# Include both existing and new has_many nested objects in fields_for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not sure how to ask this properly so I don't know if Google already has the answer (probably, though).

I have two models:

```rb
class Vocabulary < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :vocabulary_pairs
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :vocabulary_pairs
    attr_accessor :vocabulary_pairs_attributes
end
```

```rb
class VocabularyPair < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vocabulary
end
```

A condensed version of my form:

```
<%= form_for @vocabulary, url: { action: 'update' } do |vocabulary_form| %>
    <h3><%= @vocabulary.name %></h3>
    <%= vocabulary_form.fields_for :vocabulary_pairs, @vocabulary.vocabulary_pairs.build do |pair_field| %>
        <%= pair_field.text_field :origin, class: 'form-control' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In one view (`vocabularies#show`) and form, I'd like people to be able to

- View/edit existing associations between the model (so show all `VocabularyPairs` for every `Vocabulary`)
- Create new associations by pre-creating an arbitrary (say 10) amount of empty association forms.

How can I leverage `fields_for` to combine these two? Is it considered good practice to even try to? Is there a *best way* for this?

Comment: replace `@vocabulary.vocabulary_pairs.build`  with `@vocabulary.vocabulary_pairs || @vocabulary.vocabulary_pairs.build ` @lennart

Comment: Look at [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for creating new associations. It is better than pre-create them